# Registro de usuario guardando en dos tablas en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy con un sistema donde quiero guardar en dos (o más) tablas diferentes registros relacionados con el cliente.

La base es que el cliente se registra en el sistema y se crea en una tabla `clients` su ID con otra información. Ahí quiero guardar cosas específicas relacionada al cliente.

El tema es que yo creé un proyecto con autenticación de laravel, y sucede que al crear el registro, luego de eso se loguea automáticamente. No tengo problemas con eso, pero no sé cómo hacer para que antes de loguearse se guarde el registro correspondiente en la tabla `clients`.

Calculo que tengo que editar el controlador **RegisterController** pero no sé cómo hacerlo:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'user_type' => 2
        ]);
    }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme!

-- UPDATE --

EL modelo Client:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(User::Class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quieres que al mismo tiempo que ocurre el insert en users ocurra en clients?

Comment: Agrega más detalles de tu modelo clients por favor

Comment: @BetaM Excato, al mismo tiempo que hace el insert en users, haga uno con el id del nuevo user en la tabla clients. Ahí coloqué el modelo client.

Comment: Que versión de Laravel estás usando?

Comment: @BetaM la versión 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues dado que usas el sistema de registro y autenticación de Laravel, puedes dentro del mismo **`RegisterController`**  generar el insert para el siguiente modelo llamado `Client`.

Entonces debes:

- Importar el namespace de la clase del modelo deseado

  ```
  use App\Client;
  ```
- Una vez que tienes acceso a dicha entidad, debes verificar que en tu modelo `Client` tengas la [propiedad `$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) con las propiedades que permitirás sean susceptibles de asignación masiva (*esto para que puedas usar de nuevo el [método `create`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)*)

  ```
  protected $fillable = ['propiedad1', 'propiedad2', ....., 'propiedadN'];
  ```
- Ahora a tu `create` donde registras al usuario, lo asignarás a una variable

  ```
  $nuevoUsuario = User::create([................]);
  ```
- Para proceder con el alta del usuario pero en `Client` tomamos a la variable anterior que nos da acceso al objeto creado y de ahi sacar el id

  ```
  $nuevoCliente = Client::create([
      'propiedad1' => $nuevoUsuario->id,
       ................................
       ................................
  ]);
  ```

Al final puedes dar de alta así o creando [una instancia de la clase `Client`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts) (*eso ya es elección tuya*), en ambos casos después de recuperar el id del objeto recién creado solo debes complementar las propiedades extra con algún valor asignado.

Answer (score 2):

Excelente @BetaM. Gracias por la ayuda.

Ahora ya está guardando en ambas tablas en la DB.
El único detalle que tuve que agregar es un return para que haga correctamente el login automático.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $newUser = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'user_type' => 2
        ]);

        $newClient = Client::create([
            'user_id' => $newUser -> id
        ]);

        return $newUser;
    }
```